# how to jump to particular section of scrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sorting, uiscrollview

Hello Guys:
I have a scrollView in which I've populated some uibuttons horizontally. The buttons actually have my text content in their title and are arranged alphabetically. As the content is quite much so user have to scroll n scroll if he wants to get to "H" from "A", I wanna know that how can i enable user to jump to a particular area depending on alphabet sorting.. like that happen in contacts app. There 'll be alphabets written and when user hits any alphabet scrollView scrolls to the first button starting with that character. Any ideas ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at -[UIScrollView setContentOffset:animated:]